# Using a variable in an SQL query (Oracle DBMS)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am typing SQL queries to get some data from a software tool which is based on an Oracle database. I am using the typical `SELECT`-statement.

Now, in my SQL-query I am using at different places the date "02.05.2012". Is there a way to define a variable `date_string` at the beginning and then use at all relevant places this variable?

This would simplify things a lot. Thanks for all hints and tips!

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? SQL*Plus, SQL Developer?

Comment: I am typing in the SQL queries in a specific box within the software tool I use. This box takes in SQL queries and outputs the results. So, I guess, I am using a built-in client, which unfortunately doesn't support any of the suggested solutions from below. Perhaps, it's a very light SQL client and doesn't support my requested variable-functionality ?! The documentation of the software tool hasn't given me any hints either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try to rewrite your query to return the literal from an inline view ...

```
select
   my_date,
   ...
from(
   select to_date('02.05.2012','DD.MM.YYYY') my_date from dual),
   table2
where
   some_column <= my_date
```

Answer (score 2):

What you look for is a bind variable.

```
select to-date(:date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') date1
,      to-date(:date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1 date2
from   dual
```

On runtime you need to pass the value to the bind variable. It all depends on your programming language how to bind the variable, but there is plenty documentation for that.
DEFINE only works if you use sql*plus, and that's usually not the case inside a "software tool" :)

**EDIT:**

I'm beginning to understand now. It's just a textarea where you can enter a query and it will execute it and return the result. In that case you either write some complicated pl/sql code, or enter all the dates manually, or use a cross join with a select from dual:

```
with (select to_date('02.05.2012', 'dd.mm.yyyy') my_date from dual) d
select *
from   some_table t
cross join d -- no ON required
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The reason may be that I have not a typical SQL client but am processing SQL queries through a built-in tool of the software that I use. See my response above to "a_horse_with_no_name".

Comment: Great. This idea works perfectly though I implemented it as is described in a comment above to make it work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select using the current date you can use sysdate.

Using SQLPLUS you can define your own variables:

```
SQL> define mydate ="01-05-2012"

SQL> select to_date('&mydate','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;

01-MAY-12
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE to_char(date1,'DD/MM/YYYY') = '&&date'
   AND to_char(date2,'DD/MM/YYYY') = '&&date'
   AND to_char(date3,'DD/MM/YYYY') = '&&date'
```

you will get a prompt to enter the value for the &&date , if you want to enter different values for each date, you should type &date instead of &&date

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The reason may be that I have not a typical SQL client but am processing SQL queries through a built-in tool of the software that I use. See my response above to "a_horse_with_no_name".

Answer (score 0):

[DEFINE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm) is useful for your requirement.

```
DEFINE NAME="example"
```

access with `&NAME`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The reason may be that I have not a typical SQL client but am processing SQL queries through a built-in tool of the software that I use. See my response above to "a_horse_with_no_name".